# how to implement search on a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

//MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String JSON_URL = "http://kedaiagan.000webhostapp.com/kedaiagan/kedaiagan/menus.php";
        List menusList;
        ListView listView;
        private Button btnKirimPesan;
        EditText nomeja;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

```
    //initializing objects
    private void inisialisasi(){
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        menusList = new ArrayList<>();
        btnKirimPesan= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnKirimPesan);
        nomeja = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_meja);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inisialisasi();

        //this method will fetch and parse the data
        loadMenuList();

        btnKirimPesan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {

                    View v = getViewByPosition(i, listView);
                    String id_menu = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewIdMenu)).getText().toString();
                    String ket_menu = ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textKeterangan)).getText().toString();
                    String qty_menu = ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textQuantity)).getText().toString();

                    JSONObject pesanan = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        if(!qty_menu.equals("")) {
                            if (Integer.valueOf(qty_menu) >= 1) {
                                pesanan.put("id_menu", id_menu);
                                pesanan.put("keterangan", ket_menu);
                                pesanan.put("jumlah_porsi", qty_menu);
                                jsonArray.put(pesanan);
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                String url = "http://kedaiagan.000webhostapp.com/kedaiagan/kedaiagan/insertpesanan.php";

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                builder.setTitle("Pesanan Terkirim");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {

                                        nomeja.setText("");
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HalUtama.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                volleyError.printStackTrace();

                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("nomeja", nomeja.getText().toString());
                        params.put("pesanan", jsonArray.toString());
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                Process.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addTorequestque(stringRequest);
            }

            public View getViewByPosition(int position, ListView listView) {
                final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

                if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition ) {
                    return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, listView.getChildAt(position), listView);
                } else {
                    final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
                    return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
                }
            }

        });
    }
    public void getTotalHeightofListView() {

        ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int height = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

            mView.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            height = mView.getMeasuredHeight();
            totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();

        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1))
                + height;
        Log.i("Height", "" + totalHeight);
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }



    private void loadMenuList() {
        //getting the progressbar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //making the progressbar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        //creating a string request to send request to the url
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hiding the progressbar after completion
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        try {
                            //getting the whole json object from the response
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                            //we have the array named hero inside the object
                            //so here we are getting that json array
                            JSONArray menuArray = obj.getJSONArray("menus");

                            //now looping through all the elements of the json array
                            for (int i = 0; i < menuArray.length(); i++) {
                                //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
                                JSONObject menuObject = menuArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                //creating a hero object and giving them the values from json object
                                Menus menu = new Menus(menuObject.getString("nama_menu"), menuObject.getString("id_menu"));

                                //adding the hero to herolist
                                menusList.add(menu);
                            }

                            //creating custom adapter object
                            final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(menusList, getApplicationContext());

                            //adding the adapter to listview
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            getTotalHeightofListView();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });



        //creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //adding the string request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

//MyListAdapter.java

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Menus> {

    //the hero list that will be displayed
    List<Menus> menusList;

    //the context object
    Context mCtx;

    //here we are getting the herolist and context
    //so while creating the object of this adapter class we need to give herolist and context
    public MyListAdapter(List<Menus> menusList, Context mCtx) {
        super(mCtx, R.layout.my_custom_list, menusList);
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.menusList = menusList;
    }


    //this method will return the list item
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //getting the layoutinflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);

        //creating a view with our xml layout
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_list, null, true);

        //getting text views
        TextView textViewName = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewIdMenu = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewIdMenu);


        //Getting the hero for the specified position
        Menus hero = menusList.get(position);

        //setting hero values to textviews
        textViewName.setText(hero.getNama_menu());
        textViewIdMenu.setText(hero.getId_menu());

        //returning the listitem
        return listViewItem;
    }

}
```

//Menus.java

```
public class Menus {
    String nama_menu;
    String id_menu;


    public Menus(String nama_menu, String id_menu) {
        this.nama_menu = nama_menu;
        this.id_menu = id_menu;
    }


    public String getNama_menu() {
        return nama_menu;
    }

    public String getId_menu() {
        return id_menu;
    }
}

 1. List item
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is that you use GSON to parse JSON string to POJOs and from there you'll get the list of type POJO and from there you can apply required filters on the list to generate a required list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListHandler{

   private ArrayList<POJO_Name> metrics;

   public ArrayList<POJO_Name> getMetrics() {
    return metrics;
   }

   public void setMetrics(ArrayList<POJO_Name> metrics) {
    this.metrics = metrics;
   }
}
```

This will generate an instance of list that you'll get from parsing the JSON using GSON. And for the parsing process

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
 Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
 ListHandler handler= gson.fromJson(json_string, POJOName.class);
```

Just make sure you POJO must be serialized. If you like to create POJO without pain I suggest you to use [JSON to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org).

Now all is done just create a method that will return you a new list after applying conditions over the base list so that you don't mess the base list.